# JS Function to update an image without refresh? (Facebook Graph IP Used)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, facebook-graph-api

I have a web site that I'm making, and it is supposed to "hack" a Facebook account, but it's not it's just like a fake site with the functions to make it look realistic (loading bar, etc.).

I have a form where the user will input the Facebook profile link. What I need it to do upon clicking the Submit button is too take UserID of the user submitted profile link and use it to utilize the graph.facebook.com API. It needs to replace the defult_avatar.jpg image originally their with the Facebook profile avatar, and below the image the Facebook username.

I know that I can grab this data using this below:

graph.facebook.com/UserID/picture (grabs avatar)

and

graph.facebook.com/UserID?feilds=id,name (grabs selective account information)

Can anyone help with this issue I'm having? I think I need a Javascript function to change the image, I just don't know what to do. :(

Comment: What is the issue you're having?  It seems that all you need to do is change the source attribute of an image tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
document.getElementById("image_id").src="graph.facebook.com/UserID/picture";
```